# Join multiple tables and return last record from table 2

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.1

I have few tables `table1`, `table2`, `table3` and `table4`. All these tables have a relationship `MyID`.  `Table2` may have one or more records, but I'm only interested in the last inserted record.

I wrote the following query to get the desired output, however, `table2` is still returning more than one record.

```
var query = (from t1 in table1
            join t2 in table2
                on t1.MyID equals t2.MyID
                into t2Table
            join t3 in table3
                on t1.MyID equals t3.MyID 
                into t3Table
            join t4 in table4
                on t1.MyID equals t4.MyID 
                into t4Table
            where t1.MyID == 1
            select new MyViewModel()
            {
                A = t1.A,
                B = t1.B,
                C = t1.C,
                D = t2Table
                    .OrderByDescending(x => x.MyDate)
                    .Select(x => x.D).First(),
                E = t2Table
                    .OrderByDescending(x => x.MyDate)
                    .Select(x => x.E).First(),
                F = t2Table
                    .OrderByDescending(x => x.MyDate)
                    .Select(x => x.F).First(),
                G = t3Table.Select(c => new TModel()
                {
                    Col1 = c.Col1,
                    Col1 = c.Col2,
                }).ToList(),
                H = t4Table.Select(l => new PModel()
                {
                    Col1 = l.Col1,
                    Col2 = l.Languages.Col2,
                }).ToList(),
            });
```

For `D, E, F`, I have also tried selecting `.Max()`, but still same result. How can I get the latest record from `table2` using `join`?

Comment: IIRC the prefered way to do that is to sort it, then get only the 1 top/bottom record.

Comment: you want to group -- it is a function in linq

Comment: @Hogan, I tried something like this, but it's complaining about the syntax.  `D = t2Table.GroupBy(i => i.MyID).Select(g => new { MyID = g.Select(x=> x.MyID)})`. Is this what you were thinking?

Comment: What EF is this (6 or Core)? If Core, what exact version?

Comment: @IvanStoev, `Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql 2.1.2`.

Comment: could you specify, what do you mean with "table2 still returning more than one row"? `First()` can't return more than one row... Is there any exception you're getting? Or do you mean: the `query` object should have just one row?

Comment: @Marty, correct! I'm expecting to have one row (latest entry) to be returned by `table2`. However, `table2` has two records for that ID and only one record in `table1`. I'm getting both records (sorted by desc) in my query.

Comment: @smr5 so just to be extra clear (then I should be able to write you an answer): your `query` object returns multiple items, each of which has different properties D,E and F. And you want just one item from the WHOLE query, which has D,E and F from the last item from table2. Correct?

Comment: @Marty, correct. `table2` has two rows for that `MyID`. I'm interested in three columns, `D, E and F` from the record that has the most recent time stamp. Current query, will return both frows from `table2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use explicit joins. Rewrite your query the following way:

```
var query = table1
        .Where(t1 => t1.MyID == 1)
        .Select(t1 => new MyViewModel()
        {
            A = t1.A,
            B = t1.B,
            C = t1.C,
            D = table2.Where(t2 => t2.MyID == t1.MyID).OrderByDescending(x => x.MyDate).Select(x => x.D).FirstOrDefault(),
            E = table2.Where(t2 => t2.MyID == t1.MyID).OrderByDescending(x => x.MyDate).Select(x => x.E).FirstOrDefault(),
            F = table2.Where(t2 => t2.MyID == t1.MyID).OrderByDescending(x => x.MyDate).Select(x => x.F).FirstOrDefault(),
            G = table3.Where(t3 => t3.MyID == t1.MyID).Select(c => new TModel()
            {
                Col1 = c.Col1,
                Col2 = c.Col2,
            }).ToList(),
            H = table4.Where(t4 => t4.MyID == t1.MyID).Select(l => new PModel()
            {
                Col1 = l.Col1,
                Col2 = l.Languages.Col2,
            }).ToList(),
        });
```

For the moment we'll disregard the possible performance optimizations. This should have your desired result. Also note, that I fixed the assignment for the G property (you had there the `Col1` assigned twice. I also switched from using `First()` to `FirstOrDefault()` as this should be more safe and robust (although I'm not sure how the MySql will be different).

Comment: thank you for the response. I will try this. However, unfortunately, I cannot disregard the performance, as I’m doing this to improve the performance on this piece. I have a working query that gives me the result I want, but the performance lacks. That’s why I’m writing using join. Even though my query returns an extra row, the performance is actually better than the working query.

Comment: @smr5: sure, try using this approach, and if you're not happy with the performance, I will try providing you something better. Currently due to lack of time was this the best short term solution to your issue.